# How do I transparent a WebGL object via fragment shader?

Tags: webgl

If I have a matrix like this:

```
1 1 1 0 0 1
1 1 1 0 0 1
1 1 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 1
1 1 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 0 0 1
```

It represents the alpha values of a `6x6` pixel image, I wonder is it possible to transparent this image at the `0`s position ?

I notice `gl_FragColor` may be useful, but I don't know how.

=== NOTE ===
I need to do this because the client side seed me this matrix and want to transparent some place of an image, I can't change the client side's code.

Comment: How do you "transparent" an image? "Transparent" is not a verb. Do you mean to make the image transparent?

Comment: I mean transparent part of the image. :D

Comment: It is not *grammatically* possible to "transparent" something. It's like saying you want to "*useful* part of an image" or "*client* part of the image". It doesn't make sense. Do you want to *make* part of the image transparent? I'm not being pedantic; I'm trying to figure out what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

`gl_FragColor` expects vec4 that is `rgba`, where 4th float is Alpha channel and is accepting alpha value.
So in your fragment shader you need first to get pixel based on Texture Coordinates. If alpha matrix you are getting from client side is in texture, then just use `texture2D`, if it is single dimension array of floats, then you have to extract it your self based on Texture Coordinates.
Assuming that width and height of 2d array would be 6x6:

```
float alpha = alphaMat[floor(uv.y * 6) * 6 + floor(uv.x * 6)];
```

Here you transform UV to integer based on width and height of alpha array. alphaMat - is single dimension array containing alpha values, in case with 6x6 map it should have 36 floats.

It would be much more efficient to use texture instead of array, as it would allow you to apply interpolation of fragments (texture filtering).